# Firefox always shows spinning wheel when load one website, no content appear

Tags: http, firefox

When I try to use Firefox to access an internal website http://10.168.25.1:3080/, the browser shows spinning wheel, no content appear.

1. telnet tested, IP 10.168.25.1 and port 3080 is OK.
2. System Solaris 10.
3. Some other computer can Firefox or IE to this URL with expected page content (some java applet).
4. Another computer with Windows also same issue with Firefox or IE

Snoop "snoop -o ema1.pcap 10.168.25.1" result：

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000       10.82.14.173          10.168.25.1           TCP      66     48126→3080 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=49640 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 1: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_c0:ee:50 (c4:34:6b:c0:ee:50), Dst: ExtremeN_82:0d:b5 (00:04:96:82:0d:b5)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.82.14.173, Dst: 10.168.25.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 48126, Dst Port: 3080, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 0.248140       10.168.25.1           10.82.14.173          TCP      66     3080→48126 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128

Frame 2: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: ExtremeN_82:0d:b5 (00:04:96:82:0d:b5), Dst: HewlettP_c0:ee:50 (c4:34:6b:c0:ee:50)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.168.25.1, Dst: 10.82.14.173
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 3080, Dst Port: 48126, Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 0.248156       10.82.14.173          10.168.25.1           TCP      54     48126→3080 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=49640 Len=0

Frame 3: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_c0:ee:50 (c4:34:6b:c0:ee:50), Dst: ExtremeN_82:0d:b5 (00:04:96:82:0d:b5)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.82.14.173, Dst: 10.168.25.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 48126, Dst Port: 3080, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 0.248223       10.82.14.173          10.168.25.1           HTTP     339    GET / HTTP/1.1

Frame 4: 339 bytes on wire (2712 bits), 339 bytes captured (2712 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_c0:ee:50 (c4:34:6b:c0:ee:50), Dst: ExtremeN_82:0d:b5 (00:04:96:82:0d:b5)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.82.14.173, Dst: 10.168.25.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 48126, Dst Port: 3080, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 285
Hypertext Transfer Protocol

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 0.494740       10.168.25.1           10.82.14.173          TCP      60     3080→48126 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=286 Win=15744 Len=0

Frame 5: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: ExtremeN_82:0d:b5 (00:04:96:82:0d:b5), Dst: HewlettP_c0:ee:50 (c4:34:6b:c0:ee:50)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.168.25.1, Dst: 10.82.14.173
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 3080, Dst Port: 48126, Seq: 1, Ack: 286, Len: 0

**No more network communication**

Answer (score 0):

snooped from client and server, client's HTTP request successfully reached server, but server's HTTP response was being  sending back, like some network issue blocked the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a post from a long time ago but something to notice is that RTT is ~250ms. If the response from server is long, like a few MB's, it might take a long time to arrive. If you look at the advertised window from client 10.82.14.173, the advertised window is only 49KB which is not enough if the server is sending a response of some MB's with this latency. The time for the response to arrive could be more 250ms * 20 = 5sec for only 1MB. If it's 6MB or more, it will take +30sec and the web browser may be timing out.